# How to load bundles in a Symfony console component-based application?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, symfony-3.3

I am probably having some fundamental issue with understanding the Symfony Console component. I am trying to write a console-based application and I wanted to add the Doctrine bundle to it to create ORM-based entities, however, I am not able to load the bundle into my application.

What I found is that I should create `app/AppKernel.php` and add the bundle there:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    );
    return $bundles;
}
```

I have then also added the AppKernel to the composer.json and dumped composer's autoload files:

```
"classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php" ]
```

However, I am still unable to see any Doctrine commands in my console application's entry point. I don't even think the Kernel is loaded properly, the most confusing part to me is the difference between these two files on Github. First you have the Console component's `Application.php` which uses strings for its constructor parameters:

https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Application.php

And then there's the same file in the Symfony Framework and that one uses the Kernel as a parameter:

https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Console/Application.php

So am I completely on the wrong path here? How do I load bundles / Kernels in a Console Component application? Or do I need the full Symfony package to do this sort of thing? That would seem kind of overkill if I just needed to write a somewhat complex terminal application.

Just in case it is any use, these are the relevant packages in my `composer.json`:

```
"symfony/console": "v3.3.*",
"symfony/yaml": "v3.3.*",
"doctrine/orm": "~2.5",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "~1.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a console command which extends the ContainerAwareCommand as described here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Then you can call:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Which gives you the EntityManager allowing you to use Doctrine in your command line application. There is no need to edit your AppKernel or composer file to get Doctrine working.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Does that mean I would have to manually implement commands like `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`?

Comment: No, the command `doctrine:database:create` is there by default. Just type `php bin/console` and you should see a list of all available commands.

Comment: By the way, did this answer fully work for you? If so, please click the checkmark by the answer to indicate that it's the correct answer.

Comment: No, that's the thing, I cannot run the command because I only have the console component, not the full Symfony Framework. The issue I am trying to solve is to make the doctrine commands available which does not work because the bundles cannot be hooked into my console binary via the AppKernel. The bundle is what registers these commands alongside some other preparations, which is why they are not available in my application. Surely there must be a way to load bundles into only the console component? Otherwise it seems rather limited when standalone.

Comment: How did you create your Symfony project? Supposed your project is called `test`, then from the command line you should run `symfony new test`. This creates all you need including the ability to run the `doctrine:database:create` command. You then simply need to create your command source code. This should work; can you try that? Create a new project.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Might want to read the question again.  They specifically do not want to use the Symfony framework.